# Ionic: Cordova plugin not updating

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I want to change the Barcode scanner plugin for Cordova a bit, so forked it and [changed something](https://github.com/binoculars88/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner/blob/master/src/android/LibraryProject/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/result/URIResultHandler.java) rather simple for testing purposes.

As you can see on line 87, I changed the `result_uri` to `result_text` . This way, when I would scan a URL, the information would say I scanned plain text.

Then, I added this plugin to my Ionic project, using `cordova plugin add https://github.com/binoculars88/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner` .

Browsing to the files in my text editors does show my edits. But... when I run the application on my device, it keeps saying "URL Found".

It's like my changes don't apply... Anyone knows what to do? Thanks a bunch!

**UPDATE:**
I've tried changing the text itself in the `strings.xml` file, just for testing.
I've noticed that this indeed needs a remove and re-add of the platform and plugin. After that, the text is changed.

So changes in `strings.xml` do apply, but the original problem remains: changes in a `.java` file don't seem to apply.

The ultimate goal of this testing, is to make the duration time after a code is scanned (and the result text is shown) smaller. In `CaptureActivity.java`, I've changed `DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS = 1500L` to `DEFAULT_INTENT_RESULT_DURATION_MS = 15L` , but the duration time stays the same, even after removing and re-adding android platform and plugin.

Comment: Try eliminating the Android platform and re-add all the plugins again

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @AndrésFelipeGarcíaOrtiz eliminating the Android platform and re-adding the plugins seems to work with the .xml-files, but not with the .java files (see update in original post).

Comment: did you got any solution for this problem? how to easily update a plugin using ionic

Comment: Seems like every plugin I'm using is updating when I remove and re-add android platform, expect for BarcodeScanner... weird.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing work on the `cordova-plugin-camera-preview` and running these commands in succession seems to work:

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
ionic cordova platform add android
ionic cordova run android
```

I've set those commands as an alias so I can quickly recompile the .java files in the plugin.

I am still having issues though, I have added some functions to the plugin .java file but when I go to call those functions in my `home.page.ts` file, it says they don't exist.