# Modify class in jar: android build failed

Tags: java, android, jar

I want to change something in the jar file of the Barcode Scanner plugin for cordova, namely the `RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS` in the `CaptureActivity class`.

I unzipped it using the terminal (I'm on a mac).

Then, using [ClassEditor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/classeditor/files/), I looked up the class CaptureActivity, and changed the value.
Next, I re-archived it using `jar cfv samenameasoriginal.jar *` .
Then, I replaced the original jar-file for the new one.

The problem is, when I try to build it using ionic, I get a long list of errors, containing:

> UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
>   com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: bad attribute length; expected
>   length 00000002 ... ...while parsing
>   com/google/zxing/client/android/CaptureActivity.class

I've noticed that the new jar-file is 7 kb bigger than the original one, although I only changed the number 1500 to 9500, so that's a bit weird.

Anyone who can help me out? Looked online but found nothing...

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this?

Comment: When the barcode scanner scans a code, it shows a message like "URL Found" or "Text Found" for a little less then 2 seconds. I want to eliminate this delay because in my app it's key that the scanning is fast. I first tried changing the .java files of the plugin, but that didn't got me much further: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31965298/ionic-cordova-plugin-not-updating

Comment: Why don't you extend the classes you are using and change their code? the behavior? Why hack the jar when you can use OOP?

Comment: I'm new to this. How would this work? I've forked it on github.com, changed the code and then installed my fork, didn't work. See url in my previous comment.

Comment: I think you use http://jd.benow.ca/ and decompile to java files and create a new project in eclipse and create a custom from that.

Comment: If you change something in an android archive you should resign the archive again.

Comment: Isn't the message shown from a callback? Maybe you can show the message on a TextView when the callback is triggered

Answer (score 1):

Extend from the class and adjust the value:

```
public class CustomCaptureActivity extends CaptureActivity {

    RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS = 9500; // wheras 9500 is your custom value
}
```

Instead of calling `CaptureActivity` now user your custom class.

If `RESULT_DISPLAY_DURATION_MS` is read-only: Copy & paste the methods using this variable to your custom class and replace the variable with a new constant defined in your own class. As long as `CaptureActivity` is not `final` this hopefully does the trick for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is because when you are creating the JAR, there are some links that may relate to the old version of the file (because of optiomination reasons) and everything just crashes.

Not sure, but I think that's the reason.

So, instead of changing the file, you can use or a Decorator Design Patter (better idea, if possible) subclassing the class that you need to change with the changes ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern ) or you can use reflection to modify directly the library.

Here there's an example of how to change a private final field. You can do something similar:

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;

public class EverythingIsTrue {
     static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
         field.setAccessible(true);

         Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
         modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
         modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

         field.set(null, newValue);
     }

     public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {      
         setFinalStatic(Boolean.class.getField("FALSE"), true);

         System.out.format("Everything is %s", false); // "Everything is true"
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is, that some of your jar files does not compile. You should go into your build path (set all dependent path) file in your project, and look in your dependencies.

If you're just importing some jar files, you could try to remove them and add them one at a time. This will help you determine which one of them causes the error.

In my case, I did just that, and when I was importing the last one, the app compiled. So I think the real problem was that I was importing too many at once. But now it all works.